# Need to build an extremely simple one page/script site that redirects all possible links of one domain to another site

Tags: html, web, build, dns, forwarding

I want to build a site where any link to my domain such as domain.com/fefeg or domain.com/rfggtg the (/xxxxx) part will be randomly generated, always redirects to another domain.

Basically, any link with my domain + /xxxxx or even /xxx/xxx, will forward to another domain of my choosing such as otherdomain.com/x/index.php or whatever.

Godaddy has a forwarding option but doesnt forward if there is more to the link other than the plain domain name

How can i make this on my plain server? Is there a simple one file script to be uploaded to server that does this?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=webserver+redirect+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: This is a question for WebMaster, and you need to google .htaccess or the equivalent of your server setup. It sounds like a URL shortener

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache web server yes as commenter already mentioned, you need to adjust the .htaccess file to something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This should redirect for every url in the domain with a 302 temporary redirect http response to the client.

Comment: And could you tell me how to host it? Don’t know much about setting up sites. I do have a site on Linux with cpanel? I think it’s also Apache lol. Anyway so I set up my host and insert only one file the htaccess file right?